# Rails Postgres migration without downtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Let's say I want to add a column on my `users` table running the following migration

```
class AddVersionHistoryToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :versions, :string, array: true, default: '{}'
    User.find_each do |user|
      if user.app_version?
        user.versions << user.app_version.to_s
        user.save!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My aim is to insert the current `app_version` of each user into the `versions` array. How can I execute a migration without a lock in the users table due to the default value?

Comment: Pure sql seems to fit your task better, and it's pretty unclear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Add default on rails level, with before_save hook, and run the migration manually from your server command line (bundle exec rake db:migrate)

Comment: @TheCha͢mp I'm creating a new column to keep the history of app versions of the users and update it each time the version changes, so I'm initializing the values of `user.versions` to the current version, if any

Comment: ok my answer works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wrap this up: Looping and querying the database for every `User` is *highly* inefficient. You should use [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) for these tasks.

And since your data already exists in the same table you can simply get it from there.

```
User.where.not(app_version: nil).update_all('versions = ARRAY[app_version]')
```

Comment: and if the lock problem is still existing, you can just add a second migration

Comment: I see - the W lock problem is gone and is not necessary to split the migration in 2.